# How to auto number till merge cell is detected?

Tags: excel, vba

My knowledge in VBA coding is zero. I wonder if someone can help with this question, please. 
I have this initial code tried to write but it is wrong. I was not sure how to add these below conditions in the code.

Question: I want to auto number column A which starts at a specific Cell, A3 and it auto-numbers as long as there is text in Column B and Column C. 
Here's the sample data picture. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
Sub test()
    Set r = Range("a3", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1)
    With r
        If .MergeCells <> True Then
            r = r +1
        Else
            ' Skip
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your sheet is named `Sheet1`, you may use something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, counter As Long
    With Sheet1
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To lastRow
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2)) And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 3)) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = counter
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** Using `IsEmpty` to check if any of the cells in columns B & C is empty **already covers the case of cells being merged** because in that case, at least one of the two cells has to be empty anyway.

#### Demo:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You have `r` as a range, you can't add a number to it and have it increment the range. (Though I did just test it and it doesn't throw an error which is strange)

Also Skip is not a thing in VBA, if you want to skip in a loop you need a conditional or a goto. Though you have no loop.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    counter = 1
    With ActiveSheet ' Change this to the real sheet name
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Gets Last row

        For i = 3 To lastrow ' Loop
            If not isempty(.Cells(i, 2).Value) And not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then ' Looks for Text
                If Not .Cells(i, 1).MergeCells Then ' Looks for merged cells
                    .Cells(i, 1).Value = counter ' Adds count
                    counter = counter + 1 ' Increments count
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

See for comments and customize to fit your needs:

```
Public Sub AutoNumber()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim initialCellAddress As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim columnNumber As Long
    Dim counter As Long


    ' Customize to fit your needs
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    initialCellAddress = "B2"
    counter = 1

    ' Get column number and last row number to define the range address ahead
    columnNumber = Range(initialCellAddress).Column
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Define the range to be evaluated
    Set evalRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range(initialCellAddress & ":" & Left$(initialCellAddress, 1) & lastRow)

    ' Loop through each cell in range (in the original example we'll loop through column b)
    For Each evalCell In evalRange

        If evalCell.MergeCells <> True Then

            ' Assign the counter to the column at the left (offset = -1) of the evaluated cell
            evalCell.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Value2 = counter

            counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next evalCell

End Sub
```